# OutOfMemoryException: using DbContext in Task

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, dbcontext

This is the following setup I'm currently dealing with:

- I got a sql-table with ~1.000.000 entries I need to update
- the update takes place in a seperate thread (started by a task)
- as the memory is limited in a thread, i process the list in batches of 1000 entries per batch
      (when running this in a test-project in the mainthread/without any task, there is no OOM exception)
- the `UpdateList()` function either updates fields of the list or creates new record for this or other tables in the DbContext
- in the `Process_Failure()` function, I have a single context instance for the entire list
- in the `Process_Success()` function, I moved the `while`-loop outside of the context

---

```
private void Process_Success()
{
    var totalProcessedCounter = 0;

    while( true )
    {
        using( var context = new MyDbContext() )
        {
            var list = context.MyClass.OrderBy( x => x.Id )
                .Skip( totalProcessedCounter ).Take( 1000 )
                .ToList();

            if( !list.Any() )
                break;

            UpdateList( list );

            totalProcessedCounter += list.Count;
        }
    }
}

private void Process_Failure()
{
    var totalProcessedCounter = 0;

    using( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        while( true )
        {
            var list = context.MyClass.OrderBy( x => x.Id )
                .Skip( totalProcessedCounter ).Take( 1000 )
                .ToList(); // throws OutOfMemoryException

            if( !list.Any() )
                break;

            UpdateList( list );

            totalProcessedCounter += list.Count;
        }
    }
}

private void UpdateList( List<MyClass> list )
{
    var doSaveChanges = false;

    list = list.Where( x => SomeFilter( x ) ).ToList();

    using( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        foreach( var item in list )
        {
            ChangeItem( item );
        }

        if( doSaveChanges )
            context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Gets the `context` somehow polluted/filled when I create another instance in the nested functioncall of `UpdateList()`?

Comment: `as the memory is limited in a thread` - Stack space is limited in a thread, but heap memory is not.

Comment: You don't actually need to do a `.ToList()`. This will execute the query and dump everything into memory. Remove that, the `.Any()` will work fine without it.

Comment: As Mike says, and if you do that you shouldn't need to batch it like you are doing.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Yes, that makes sense to me. I don't know the internals of C#, but shouldn't almost every object reside on the heap? (also for larger lists?) If so, then I do not understand why I am getting OOM-exceptions when I run this in the framework started by a task and everything runs fine when I do use the code in a test-prj without the task/thread..

Comment: @MikeEason The .ToList() is usefull for the debugger, or are there other ways to see the list (more than a single entry + the count) without polluting the runtime code?

Comment: @user5997884 Yes, if you remove the `.ToList()` and step over that line, hover the cursor over the `list` variable and you should see a **Results View** within the expander. This will execute the query and you will be able to see the results. Or you could use the **Immediate Window** and execute the query there: `list.ToList()` should print out the results.

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks a ton! I've never seen this before. I guess I have to refactor alot now... :)

Comment: However, I still don't get the oom-exception. Doesn't the GC deletes prior lists that were loaded from the context? Or is the EF keeping all loaded records in memory until the context is disposed?

Comment: EF tracks every object loaded (unless `AsNoTracking` was used) until it is disposed.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you get the exception is because `DbContext` caches [the data you read from DB](http://codethug.com/2016/02/19/Entity-Framework-Cache-Busting/), therefore at some point you will blow up your memory if you keep adding entities to its cache and you will get the `OutOfMemoryException`. Entities are not cleared by the GC because they are being referenced by the `DbContext`.

Try using `.AsNoTracking()`:

```
private void Process_NoTracking()
{
    var totalProcessedCounter = 0;

    using( var context = new MyDbContext() )
    {
        while( true )
        {
            var list = context
                          .MyClass
                          .AsNoTracking()
                          .OrderBy( x => x.Id )
                          .Skip( totalProcessedCounter )
                          .Take( 1000 )
                          .ToList(); 

            if( !list.Any() )
                break;

            UpdateList( list );

            totalProcessedCounter += list.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

But if you do not track the entities, updating them [is more difficult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx) (read "Attaching an existing entity to the context"), because those entities do not belong to any context and they are not being tracked.

I would not use EF for somethng like this, this looks like a good mission for an UPDATE/SELECT SQL statement.

Comment: You could do it if you'd be `using` a new context for each batch of updates.

Comment: Of course, but it seems the OP already got to that conclusion since that is what `Process_Success` does.